# How can I have a serializable struct that wraps it's self as an int32 implicitly? in C#?

Tags: .net, serialization, struct

Long story short,  I have a struct (see below) that contains exactly one field:

private int value;

I've also implemented implicit conversion operators:

```
    public static implicit operator int(Outlet val)
    {
        return val.value;
    }

    public static implicit operator Outlet(int val)
    {
        return new Outlet(val);
    }
```

I've implemented all of the following :

```
IComparable, IComparable<Cart>, IComparable<int>, IConvertible, IEquatable<Cart>, IEquatable<int>, IFormattable
```

I'm at a point where I really have no clue why, but whenever I serialize this object, I get no value.  For instance, with XmlSerialization:

```
<Outlet />
```

Also, I'm not solely concerned about XmlSerialization, I'm concerned about ALL serialization (binary for instance)  How can I ensure that this serializes properly?

NOTE: I did this because mapping an int,int dictionary seemed rather poorly typed to me when explicit objects with validation behavior were desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML serialization only works with *public properties*, so you would need to expose a public property that sets/gets the value.

As an alternative, you can implement [IXmlSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx) to manually serialise the structure.

This is only an issue with XML serialisation. The binary serialiser will serialise private fields as well as public ones.

Comment: I was aware of the public limitation, but wasn't aware IXmlSerializable provided a way around this.  Thank you.

Comment: Still having some wierdness however.  it's only wanting to serialize my very first value the first time it hits it, for instance,
            <Slot>1</Slot>
            <Outlet>1</Outlet>
I only get Slot = 1, and outlet is never set (same basic code)